# What's the point of E_ALL | E_STRICT if it's the same value as E_ALL?

Tags: php, error-reporting

- `E_ALL` equals 8191 (`0001 1111 1111 1111`)
- `E_STRICT` equals 2048 (`0000 1000 0000 0000`)

Using bitwise OR to combine them:

```
1 1111 1111 1111
  1000 0000 0000
```

We get the **exact** same value as the original `E_ALL`:

```
1 1111 1111 1111
```

What's the point of doing `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)` if we can simply do `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to get the same thing?

Comment: I've noticed that with 5.4 that I can do the following
1. Set E_ALL in php.ini and then E_ALL | E_STRICT
2. Check phpinfo() and the value for error reporting is the same.

This seems like a bug to me....

Comment: use https://maximivanov.github.io/php-error-reporting-calculator/  to create error reporting of your choice

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

`E_ALL` does not include `E_STRICT` (unless you are using PHP 5.4+). Your values are incorrect. From [Predefined Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) `E_ALL` is defined as:

> All errors and warnings, as supported,
>   except of level `E_STRICT` prior to PHP 5.4.
>
> 32767 in PHP 5.4.x, 30719 in PHP 5.3.x,
>   6143 in PHP 5.2.x, 2047 previously

Comment: I see this means the constant values will change as the version changes. The values I found is from http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_error_reporting.asp
They are very outdated, right?

Comment: w3schools can have some very outdated information. I would ALWAYS go to php.net as a first reference for anything PHP related.

Comment: In PHP 5.4, `E_STRICT` is included in `E_ALL`.

Answer (score 3):

1 | 1 = 1

The simplest answer possible is that there's presently no reason to combine the two with a bitwise or operation, but if they ever decide to change those constants in the future, then there might be.

Edit: and you seem to have pulled the wrong values for those constants, making the entire question moot.

Answer (score 1):

from php.net:

Passing in the value -1 will show every possible error, even when new levels and constants are added in future PHP versions. The E_ALL constant also behaves this way as of PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

The bit values provided in the question are not generally wrong but only for PHP versions older than 5.4.

#### PHP 5.4+

`E_ALL` includes `E_STRICT` so you should use: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

```
Binary                  Name       Decimal
0001 1111 1111 1111     E_ALL      32767
0000 1000 0000 0000     E_STRICT   2048
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0001 1111 1111 1111     E_ALL | E_STRICT produces the same result as E_ALL
```

#### PHP 5.3

`E_ALL` does not include `E_STRICT` so you should use: `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

```
Binary                  Name       Decimal
0111 0111 1111 1111     E_ALL      30719
0000 1000 0000 0000     E_STRICT   2048
----------------------------------------------------------------------
0111 1111 1111 1111     E_ALL | E_STRICT produces a different value than E_ALL
```

#### PHP 5.0 till 5.2

`E_ALL` does not include `E_STRICT` so you should use: `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` but the bit values differ from the values in PHP 5.3.

#### PHP before 5.0

`E_STRICT` does not exist so you must use: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`