# how to off this error in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Only variables can be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967597/only-variables-can-be-passed-by-reference)

I am having this error in php

```
Only variables should be passed by reference
```

and such warnings are displaying in millions of places. How can I off this error?

Comment: Well, for one, you could write correct code :)

Comment: Pass variables rather than values to the method/function that raises the problem - easy! PHP is trying to write a value to a value, which is impossible.

Comment: (This is a very searchable problem, by the way)

Comment: Downgrade your PHP to 4.4, or change the error reporting level, OR (even better) update your code!

Comment: No, that is not a duplicate of this. This question wants the warning explained; the other is a design question about avoiding the issue in the first place (with foreknowledge of the warning's meaning).

Comment: it was working on local machine. But after uploading to remote machine this warning is displaying. I can not change whole code neither i can change php version

Comment: @Kutta: What decision process did you go through when deciding to upload to a machine running a different PHP version?

Answer (score 3):

By only passing variables by reference, not other things.

The "other things" in this case may well be the result of function calls, which are not variables.

e.g.

```
array_pop(Array(1,2,3,4));
```

`array_pop` takes a reference, but `Array(1,2,3,4)` is not a variable and *only variables can be passed by reference*.

<sup>I'd be able to give a better answer if we had any idea what even one of the pieces of your code looked like.</sup>