# Is this an incorrect way to get datetime?

Tags: php, datetime

I get datetime from this way:

```
class DB_Functions extends DB_Connect{

    private $dbConnect = "";
    public $dtime;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dbConnect = $this->pdo_connect();
        $this->dtime = new DateTime();
    }

    public function destruct() {
        $this->dbConnect = null;
    }


    public function exampleInsert() {
        .
        .
        .
        $result->bindParam(':dateCreation',$this->dtime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}
```

Then when I use **dtime** to insert in a table, like this:

```
Line 1708: $result->bindParam(':dateCreation',$this->dtime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Display this error:

```
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>include\DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>1708</b><br />
```

My declaration to get datetime is wrong?

Comment: That DB_Functions class you posted isn't 1700 lines long. What *exactly* is on line 1708?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967597/only-variables-can-be-passed-by-reference or at least related

Comment: Line 1708 is $result->bindParam(':dateCreation',$this->dtime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),PDO::PARAM_STR); the same in the post.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#111215. Function definition for bindParam says it passes the second argument by reference - meaning it must be a variable and not a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `bindParam()` which actually binds a variable to the parameter in the query.  This must be a variable, not a method call that returns a value.

This allows for usage like:

```
$value = 'somevalue';
$result->bindParam(':some_field', $value);
$value = 'someothervalue';
$result->execute(); // executes query with 'someothervalue' passed as parameter.
```

In your case you might want to use `bindValue()`. Which actually binds the value to the parameter in an immutable fashion.  Either that or store your formatted datetime into a different class variable and continue to use `bindParam()` with that new variable.